# Adding a third party event subscriber

Tags: postgis, symfony

I am relatively new to symfony, working on a project using PostgreSQL with postgis. Therefore I would like to make doctrine supporting postgis and stumbled upon this extension:
https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis

In the setup part are just two lines of code and a link referencing to the symfony documentation given.

So what I tried was adding the ORMSchemaEventSubscriber in my services.yml file:

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    my.subscriber:
        class: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Event\ORMSchemaEventSubscriber
        arguments: []
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

This approach throws an exception stating the ORMSchemaEventSubscriber class is no subclass of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface.

That is where I am stuck and not knowing what to do or where to put the given lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to register it as Symfony Kernel Listener, which it is not.

So for it to work, you have to use an appropriate tag:

```
my.subscriber:
    class: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Event\ORMSchemaEventSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

Here is Symfony Documentation about this: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Answer (score 1):

In your service definition please change `name: kernel.event_subscriber` to `name: doctrine.event_subscriber` so that it becomes:

```
services:
    my.subscriber:
        class: Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Event\ORMSchemaEventSubscriber
        arguments: []
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

More info: https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis/issues/3